# Strange lines in render

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects

I am very new to blender and I am working on some projects to help myself become more acquainted with the program. I am currently working on a mask:

[image: Revan Mask Front View]
[image: Revan Mask Angled]

Thats the material view and looks fantastic to me. But then I go to the rendered view and this happens:

[image: Revan Render Front]
[image: Revan Render Angled]

If anyone can help me solve this issue it would be very much appreciated. 
And here is the file:
 [image]

Comment: plz attach file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: well i did not get the question But then I go to the rendered view and this happens: Means??  what u need

Comment: @atek compared to the material view I posted in the first two pictures, the render has lines that should not be there and the mask seems to be extending out at the top of the cheek

Comment: In the tool shelf Add smooth shading. And in the modifier add edge split modifier

Comment: @atek Thank you very much that worked great!

Comment: Please refrain from adding "(solved)" to question titles. A solved question on bse, has an accepted answer.  Instead, Write up an answer (from comment by @atek) on how this has solved your question.

Comment: @batFINGER My apologies, first time I have used this website. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I've had that problem many times and I had to learn the hard way. The reason why your mesh looks like that in render view is because you don't have enough geometry. If you add more geometry to the parts that are causing the problem you will see the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from flat shading (instead of smoothing, as pointed out by @atek) your mesh has a few other issues: apart some ngons, which are considered bad topology, but it could work for your needs, there are a few nonplanar faces (mostly ngons), and those are causing artifacts, as visible below.

The good news is that you can find solutions to them all using the bundled 3d print addon (you just need to activate it in user preferences), as shown below:

[image]

First, I forgot to say that before using the 3d print toolbox "check all" tool, I already recalculated normals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

Then,

1. **What you should have done** is: try to not use ngons (ie: faces with more than 4 vertices) and if possible also avoid triangles. Why? Because this easily create problems, gives artifacts in 3d viewport and rendering, and behaves horribly if you need to animate deforming objects. The additional lines that have appeared in the render are the ngons being split into triangles as ngons themselves are not renderable.

It doesn't seem to be the case with this model but, since you're learning, it would immensely help you if you try to model everything with "quads" or, if really needed, "tris". Note that even "quads" could be made (by mistake) non planar, but while it is less likely, they will be much more easy to fix.

2. **What can you do now**, to improve this model? This is a difficult answer. In a few words, you need to convert those "ngons" into "quads". This goes under the name of "retolopogy", ie: create a new (better, simpler) mesh structure for a shape that already exists.

I'm not a retopology genius, and without reference images it's even harder, but I tried to "fix" a small portion of the mask, by deleting faces (only faces) and subdividing remaining edges to make them nearly match their "quad" counterparts, sometimes "sliding" vertices along an edge, and rebuilding faces based only on 4 vertices.

Now, shown below, you see that after pressing "check all" again it doesn't identify those areas as issues anymore:

[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't really explain what the user is meant to do once they've found the n-gons/non-planar faces.

Comment: @RayMairlot you're right, but I was in doubt: the question is about "strange lines" due, apparently, just to flat shading... what I show above is probably a totally different topic which probably needs another question like "how do I fix non planar faces in my model?" I just pointed out those errors in the mesh... I could add some resolution path, but I'm not sure it belongs here...

Comment: The issue is caused by the n-gons being unpredictably split at render time. The smooth shading and edge split modifier are just a workaround. Your answer gets to the root of the problem (or it will if you explain what the fix is).

Comment: @RayMairlot I've added some more content to the answer, I hope it could be considered enough for this context. Anyway he already accepted the other answer, so maybe he's no more interested :D  Imho he should add another question about fixing this mask model, and get more and better focused advices there...

Comment: Hello, I would like to sincerely thank you for the added content to explain about ngons and tris. This is my first real project with blender and I have been enjoying the process of learning what I'm doing wrong and how to improve so I appreciate your extra effort despite it not really being required by my question(: also I was in a rush at the time of accepting the other answer and didn't properly look at yours. Just to ensure I understand, if I turn my ngons into 4 vert faces it would fix the issue? Also if you go to front view in the program it has a reference image for what I want.

Comment: Don't worry about accepting my answer (btw, on this site it is perfectly fine to switch to another later answer if you wish: it's your question, you choose) I'm not that much after rep points ;-) I can see the background image set, but (any) images are never saved inside .blend files, unless you explicitly "pack" them (there's a command to do that, search this site or blender manual). You can model how you wish, but if you use quads only, and sometimes is not easy, you'll thank yourself later: it's always better.

Answer (score 3):

Switch to Edit Mode -> Flip Normal

In Object Mode -> Tool shelf -> Shading -> Smooth

In Modifier tab Add -> Edge Split Modifier

[image]

Comment: Good, but I added another answer to show some topology problem, I think he'll learn better to fix those, instead of relying on edge split modifier to make it just look better. Its' good, and non destructive, but it leaves bad topology, even applied.